# How can I show different text on click depending on object shown?

Tags: javascript, html

i have an array of different images that are changing after clicking on them, basically they have 2 states - back and front, only front image is changing, my goal is to show different text that depends on the name of front image that is currently shown, so if I have 1.img the text is "Examle 1 text" and if it is 2.img the text is "Example 2 text". I have tried different solutions but they didn't work as expected.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// Part for turning images
var images = [];

(function() {
    generateCards()
})()

var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

Array.from(cards).forEach(function(card) {
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
        Array.from(card.querySelectorAll('.back, .front')).forEach(function(el) {
            ['back', 'front'].forEach(function(s) {
                el.classList.toggle(s)
            });
        });
    });
});

//Dispalying different images on click
function cardImg(index) {
    var cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2, 10);
    if (images[index] !== undefined) {
        images[index] = -1;
    }
    while (images.indexOf(cardNewImg) != -1) {
        cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2, 10);
    }
    images[index] = cardNewImg;
}

function generateCards() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cardImg(i);
    }
}

function getCard(index) {
    if (!images[index].valid) {
        cardImg(index)
    }
    document["randimg" + (index + 1)].src = "./img/" + images[index] + ".jpg";
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Card</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front" onClick="getCard(0)"><img src="./img/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="back"><img src="./img/2.jpg" name="randimg1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front" onClick="getCard(1)"><img src="./img/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="back"><img src="./img/2.jpg" name="randimg2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front" onClick="getCard(2)"><img src="./img/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="back"><img src="./img/2.jpg" name="randimg3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden1">Text 1</div>
    <div class="hidden2">Text 2</div>
    <div class="hidden3">Text 3</div>
    <div class="hidden4">Text 4</div>
    <div class="hidden5">Text 5</div>
    <div class="hidden6">Text 6</div>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You said "didn't work as expected" but did not tell us what is happening that you didn't intend? What is the actual problem you are facing? Also is all that code relevant to your question?

Comment: I meant I didn't achieve diplaying hidden text depending on the image shown, so I don't have working solution. I also have CSS code but it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
```

On click you can get img src attribute and display proper text:

#### Disclaimer before you read code:

In below code I assume that quantity of imgs and divs with hidden text is the same and both imgs and hidden divs are already there in DOM structure.

## HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="front"><img src="./img/1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="back"><img src="./img/2.jpg" name="randimg1"></div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="front"><img src="./img/1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="back"><img src="./img/4.jpg" name="randimg2"></div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="front"><img src="./img/1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="back"><img src="./img/6.jpg" name="randimg3"></div>
</div>


<div class="hidden">Text 1</div>
<div class="hidden">Text 2</div>
<div class="hidden">Text 3</div>
<div class="hidden">Text 4</div>
<div class="hidden">Text 5</div>
<div class="hidden">Text 6</div>
```

## CSS

```
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

## Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var fronts = document.querySelectorAll('.front')

  fronts.forEach(function(front) {
      const hiddenTextsElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden")
      const imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img")
      
      //attaching click events to show random hidden div on each .front click
      front.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target)
          const clickedImgSrc = e.target.getAttribute("src")
          const randomHiddenTextNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * hiddenTextsElements.length)

          hiddenTextsElements[
            randomHiddenTextNumber
          ].style.visibility = "visible"

      });
  }); 
});
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMVpWK?editors=1011

Comment: you want to insert img.src text into hidden divs? or what? or when clicked on img.src1, display hidden1?

Comment: I guess when img1 clicked than display hidden1 text. You need to connect those elements somehow so you can recognize which text should be visualized on img click. I would add `data-imgSrc` attribute to each hidden text (I assume you have one hidden text for each img, right?) and find proper hiddenText div by src in data-imgSrc attribute. Makes sense?

Comment: @АнтонПортнянко check my answer above, I already have done that for you. You can iterate through images, or through sources of images if you have them in some separate structure and insert them into data-imgsrc attribute OR create those hiddenDivs from scratch. I dont know how you create your view and what will be better approach.

Comment: @АнтонПортнянко if this answers your question, can you mark it as answer? Thanks

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it, I have copied your code above but there is an error in console - _Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined_ What should I do? Add data-src to all div's with class="hidden"?

Comment: @АнтонПортнянко also pay attention, that all hidden text divs, **have same class**

Comment: `.front` img src is always the same in my case - `src="1.img"`, and `.back` img src is changing randomly on click, and I must display div after clicking on `.front` part, so it reverts and show random `.back` img not after clicking on `.back`

Comment: than in my example find all `.front` divs instead of `.cards` and show your random `.back` as you want. If you want hidden div also be randomized, just select all `img` tags and pick random source, showing it like I implemented it already. 
All clear now? You need to try mate :) I can't do everything for you, as tou will learn next to nothing in such process. If you have problems let me know, but please try not to tell me what you need and expect am going to just implement it, cause that is not what this page is for :) no offence friend, am just trying to explain, no hard feelings

Comment: It's ok, thank you very much for help, I'm just stuck on this part with binding diplaying div's content to dynamic data, I'm relatively new in JS and I'm searching for working options, sorry if i annoyed you. I'll try to implement your advices, thank you again for your time and help.